# Как определить четное число или нет при помощи PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день, ув. Про!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как силами исключительно PHP определить четным или не четным будет число какое-либо число месяца в будущем.
Например, с клавиатуры вводим: 22.08.2015. Как узнать, будет оно четным или нет?

Answer (score 3):

```
function even($var)
{
    // является ли переданное число четным
    return !($var & 1);
}
```

Comment: могли бы вы объяснить почему эта запись работает?

Comment: Чет или не чет определяется первым битом числа. Если там 1, то это число не четное. Если там 0, то четное. Все остальные биты это степени дойки и они всегда четные. Если мы делаем & с единицей, то все биты числа, кроме первого гарантированно сбрасываются в ноль. А первый бит будет единицей, если число не четное и нулем в противном случае.

Answer (score 1):

Число из даты такого формата можно получить функциями `explode()` или `strtok()`.
Остаток от деления в РНР получают оператором `%`

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен правильно ли, но как-то так:

```
function dateCheker($var)
{
    $date = strtotime($var);
    $day = date('d', $date);

    if ($day % 2 === 0) {
        print "even";
    } else {
        print "odd";
    }
}

dateCheker('23.08.2015');
```

Comment: Вопрос вроде бы про месяц. Поменяйте "d" на "n" для получения номера месяца без ведущего нуля

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = 1; //Число

if($num % 2 === 0)
  echo 'Четное';
else
  echo 'Нечетное';
```